# Custom Iterator for Number Prototype in JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iterator, prototype

Recently I learned about JS iterators, beeing used in a `for( of )` loops. Since in JS even primitives have a prototype, I wondered if it is possible to extend the Number prototype so that the following would be a valid expression:

```
for(let i of 10) console.log(i); //0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Obviously this would only work for integers, but is there a way to implement this?

Hopefully there is, but I wasn't able to create this myself since I'm new to this part of JS...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just define `Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator]`:

```js
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  let currentNum = 0;
  return {
    next: () => (
      currentNum == this
      ? { done: true }
      : {
        value: currentNum++,
        done: false
      }
    )
  }
}
for (const i of 10) console.log(i);
```

But mutating the built-in objects (like the global `Number`) is *very* bad practice - it would be better to find another way to do whatever you're trying to accomplish, if at all possible.

Comment: Well, I know it's bad practice, and I won't use this often, it was more of a JS experiment trying to lean something new :)

Answer (score 8):

You could take a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) for [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) as prototype for `Number`.

```js
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
};

console.log([...10]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by defining a initial value (in this case 0) and in a yield loop increment that value until the value is equal to the number:

```js
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  var value = 0;
  //< or <= depending on what you are expecting as the end number
  while(value <= this){
    //yield the value and increment
    yield value++;
  }
};
for (let i of 10) {
  console.log("num", i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the other answers I was now able to create a somewhat comprehensive prototype extension supporting negative Numbers and validation...

```js
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*(){
    if(!Number.isInteger(this.valueOf()))
        throw new TypeError("Only integers can be iterated over.");
    if(this>0)
        for(let i=0;i<this;i++)
            yield i;
    if(this<0)
        for(let i=0;i>this;i--)
            yield i;
    
};

console.log([...5]);
console.log([...-5]);
console.log([...0]);
console.log([...1.5]);
```